# Why am I getting the error "Obtained an unexpected kind of VM install" in Mulesoft's Anyponit Studio (Eclipse)?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why does everything around Java need to be so ____ complicated? I am trying to run applications - that run on other people's machines - and getting the error:

> Obtained an unexpected kind of VM install: null

Has anyone seen anything like this?

[Anypoint Studio](https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/studio) is a product provided by Mulesoft and based on Eclipse.

Mac OS X Yosemite

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T07:57:37-04:00)
Maven home: /Users/jkalis/Maven/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: No class path, no path including java?

Comment: I have Java in my path and JAVA_HOME set properly. What is class path and how do I check it? Thank you for responding.

Comment: Windows or unix: Depends on the shell. Look for the CLASSPATH parameter.

Comment: Updated the post with more ENV details.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to reference the version of the JRE that you want to use in the project properties.

Here are the steps to add it to your project.

- Select the Project
- Choose the Properties
- Choose 'Java Build Path'
- Click Libraries on the Dialog
- Choose 'Add Library...'
- Select 'JRE System Library'
- Click Next
- Choose the JRE System Library to use.
- Click Finish